# How to compare more than one string in if statement in C?

Tags: c, codeblocks, strcmp

In C language, I have created a program with a virtual bot so that when you start the program it introduces itself and I've given it the name Nick. When the user launches the program, it asks for the user's name and I want to write a code that if the user's name is similar to the names: Nick, Nicko, Nic, Nik or with capital letters: NICK, Nicko. Nic etc. the program will greet the user like: "Woah! I have the same name..." but when the user types another name that is not similar to Nick, the program will greet him like "Hello (user's name)...". Can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We love that you're here and you should show us your code.

Comment: One way that is easily maintainable is to have an array of names that are supposed to be replied to in a certain way. Loop through the array comparing each with the input and setting a flag if there is a match. If the non-standard function `stricmp` or `strcasecmp` is available that will make case differences easy. For example `char *nicknames[] = { "Nick", "Nicko", ... };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array of cstrigns (something like `char dictionary[size][size]`) and populate it with words you want to check against. Then iterate through it, checking if the input matches the current string.

Answer (score 0):

Others suggested tables of aliases, but that is a bit unwieldy if you plan to handle an arbitrary number of users.  The upper and lower case handling is relatively simple; when you store what the person typed, also store a copy of it all in one case to use for comparisons.   That way, your program can address them the way they first did.   Rather than a table, you program might encode a number of substitution rules that it can accept in a string: ie for y; n for nn, and suffixes that can be ignored.

Depending upon the number of rules, you might consider ordering the rules as a normalization function which you apply universally - so for example replace all the ie's with y, remove all ignorable suffixes, etc... - in your stored copy of the string;  apply the same normalization function to the input, and then just compare these rather than the raw ones.

Of course there are problems here, in that you wouldn't want to apply most rules at the beginning of a name, and some would only be appropriate if they were applied to a soft-vowel rather than a hard vowel; which brings in the soundex algorithm, which translates words into their phonetic equivalent, so that "science" and "scene" become farther apart than their edit distance might suggest.   At this point, you have pretty much implemented a spelling corrector.

Your problem statement is deceptively simple; there has been a lot of research in this area, and yet helpful typing assistants are anything but.